# vuetify/vujs: max height of v-row

Tags: css, vue.js

First: Im not good at Frontends and new to vue

I have 3 relativly large tables under each other. Problem is, if you want to scroll a table vertically, you have to scroll all the way down to each table and use the scrollbar there, which is not really handy.

So I want to limit the height of each `v-row` (one v-row holds one table) so the vertical scrollbar is just on the bottom of the current viewport and takes not the full height, just some %. But its just not working, I cant set height of v-row. How to achieve this?

My `Main.vue template` looks like this

```
<template>
  <div class="dashboard">
    <h1 class="subheading grey--text">Main</h1>
      <!--loading-->
      <Loader :showLoading="showLoading"/>

      <button v-on:click="getData">Greet</button>

    <v-container fluid v-if="data !== null" class="my-5">
      <v-row  v-for="(report,index) in data['reports']"
              :index="index"
              :key="report.reportName"
              style="height:20%;" //not working
              height="20%"> //also not working
        <v-col cols="12" sm="12">
          <Report :report="report" :dateType="data.dateType"/>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>

  </div>
</template>
```

`Report.vue Template` is just a table

```
<template>
      <v-simple-table dense>
        <template v-slot:default>

          <thead>
            //head
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            //body
          </tbody>

        </template>
      </v-simple-table>
</template>
```

Comment: Both `style` and `height` are not props, AFAIK (cfr. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/simple-tables/). That’s why it doesn’t work. You may better try with CSS styling in the single component.

Comment: `height` could be `20`, not `20%` as I see in the API. It treats this property as the HTML equivalent. CSS may help.

Comment: setting `height` as absolute value (so no %) on `v-simple-table`is working

Comment: Then, it was just the `style` props not working.